# Jenkins GUI very slow - fast after browser cache clear

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins master + 5 slaves setup.

The recent weeks the Jenkins GUI has started slowing down for us, up to the point that loading of Jenkins GUI periodically takes *minutes*.
After loading it is still slow, Jenkins does not feel very responsive at all.

Curiously, when I open Jenkins AND clear all browser caches (cookies, cache etc) the Jenkins GUI is blazing fast, everything loads fine then. The next day the GUI also starts to slow down, until I clear all browser cookies + caches again.
I tested this in Chrome + IE, same results.

Some things I already checked and tried:

- Check CPU + memory usage on the master (low CPU usage, plenty heap space free)
- GC logs on master (checked on gceasy - everything is alright - no suggestions)
- Cleared old data on Jenkins
- We already restricted all jobs to have a max history of 10

So, I'm out of ideas. It is something related to the browser/client since clearing the cookies/cache fixes the problem for users.

Any ideas what may be the real problem with Jenkins?

When the GUI is loaded and slow, what I see that many requests to static resources are very long pending, eg. this resource:
/static/1f01833b/images/32x32/red_anime.gif

Comment: I am having a similar issue as well--on the next occurrence I am planning to attempt to determine whether a specific cookie is causing the slowness.

Have you been able to determine whether a specific cache entry or cookie when removed seems to improve performance?

Comment: what is the master setup , aws machine , docker on k8s ?  what is the master version ?  do you use the master for running jobs , or jobs run only on slaves ?

Comment: The master is running on bare metal, not in the cloud. Windows Server 2016, 14GB RAM.

No jobs run on the master, only on slaves.

Version is the latest, we update biweekly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing with build 2.150.2.  Things load fine in incognito mode on chrome, but will start slowing down if incognito is opened for a while.  I personally have not tested IE but am in the process of testing with firefox.  After 12 hrs firefox still seems fine so may be a browser related issue. I also have access to another jenkins server running version 2.73.3, which does not have this issue.

Comment: update, firefox now also runs jenkins slowly, reinforcing @Bossk's hypothesis that it isn't browser specific.

Comment: When I remove the following cookie, the GUI is fast again:
ACEGI_SECURITY_HASHED_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE

I am opening a ticket at Jenkins jira, see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: This is the Jira ticket regarding this issue:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56243

Quite a few people are having the same problem, and Active Directory does not seem the root cause because people report having the same issue without AD integration.
Unfortunately the Jenkins developers do not seem to give it much priority...

Answer (score 12):

This cookie was causing the slowdown problems in the GUI:
ACEGI_SECURITY_HASHED_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE

When I cleared this cookie (and performed a relogin) Jenkins was very fast again.

It is not a true fix, but for us a decent workaround:

Enabling the "Disable remember me" under Configure Global Security fixed it for us (effectively removing the "Remember me" from the login screen.